# Compilation problem with WiringOP library

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone, I have a question. How to add dependencies for package.
For example, when I compilling program that used WiringOP library:

```
g++ progname.cpp  -lwiringPi -lpthread
```

So, question is how to add this dependencies in catkin workspace.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278449/compilation-problem-with-wiringop-library/) by [Amrello](https://answers.ros.org/users/31839/amrello/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2017-12-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'll want to add the names of the libraries you need to link against to the target_link_libraries tag for the node in your CMakeLists.txt file as shown below:

Change the line:

```
add_executable(<your_node_name> src/progname.cpp)
target_link_libraries(<your_node_name> ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

To:

```
add_executable(<your_node_name> src/progname.cpp)
target_link_libraries(<your_node_name> ${catkin_LIBRARIES} wiringPi pthread)
```

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Amrello](https://answers.ros.org/users/31839/amrello/) on 2018-01-03**:
Already compilled 2 days ago, but thanks

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2018-01-03**:
If you figure out an answer to your own question its helpful if you come back and share it with everyone, in case it could help others.